# Why do I need resources per swapchain image

Tags: vulkan

I have been following different tutorials and I don't understand why I need resources per swapchain image instead of per frame in flight.

This tutorial:
https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Uniform_buffers

has a uniform buffer per swapchain image. Why would I need that if different images are not in flight at the same time? Can I not start rewriting if the previous frame has completed?

Also lunarg tutorial on depth buffers says:

> And you need only one for rendering each frame, even if the swapchain has more than one image. This is because you can reuse the same depth buffer while using each image in the swapchain.

This doesn't explain anything, it basically says you can because you can. So why can I reuse the depth buffer but not other resources?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is to minimize synchronization in the case of the simple Hello Cube app.

Let's say your uniforms change each frame. That means main loop is something like:

1. Poll (or simulate)
2. Update (e.g. your uniforms)
3. Draw
4. Repeat

If step #2 did not have its own uniform, then it needs to write a uniform previous frame is reading. That means it has to sync with a Fence. That would mean the previous frame is no longer considered "in-flight".

Comment: I understand this, what I don't understand is why it's resource per swapchain image and not per frame in flight. If my swapchain has 3 images and I want at most 2 frames in flight at the same time, can I not just have a double buffer, so frame #1 renders, then frame #2 render and frame #3 waits for frame #1 and uses the same resources?

Comment: @RhuMage You best ask the author of the tutorial, but I assume because that would require re-recording buffers. resource-per-simage allows for cmdbuffers to be prebaked on setup and never changed.

Comment: That makes sense even thought it's not stated anywhere. I just want to know if I'm rerecording command buffers every frame anyway, can I get away with less than per swapchain image resources.

Comment: @RhuMage: Vulkan is not a copy-and-paste API; it should not be learned by reading some code and doing what it says. If you're going to read Vulkan code, this should be so that you understand how its API works, *not* how to structure your application for it. That part should be based on your understanding of the tools Vulkan provides and the needs of your application, not on what some tutorial said or did.

Comment: Right, in a "realistic" app you probably do not even want to keep more than two frames in flight, because you would prefer lower latency over potentially high throughput. And even so, more than two frames in flight likely gives no advantage... it is only natural to make a simple Hello app examples this way.

Comment: PS: then again uniforms are usually small, and you save next to no resources trying to optimize here...

Comment: @NicolBolas I am not copy-pasting, I am trying to understand this, but no tutorial I've read so far has explained this.

Comment: @RhuMage I think what he means is you should not take a word of a tutorial-maker as absolute. Especially in Lesson 1, where his primary concern is to get something on screen ASAP, while only glossing over many aspects of Vulkan. Especially lerning perfect app architecture should not be the point of Lesson 1, and of Hello app.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the way You are using Your resources and the performance You want to achieve.

If, after each frame, You are willing to wait for the rendering to finish and You are still happy with the final performance, You can use only one copy of each resource. Waiting is the easiest synchronization, You are sure that resources are not used anymore, so You can reuse them for the next frame. But if You want to efficiently utilize both CPU's and GPU's power, and You don't want to wait after each frame, then You need to see how each resource is being used.

Depth buffer is usually used only temporarily. If You don't perform any postprocessing, if Your render pass setup uses depth data only internally (You don't specify `STORE` for `storeOp`), then You can use only one depth buffer (depth image) all the time. This is because when rendering is done, depth data isn't used anymore, it can be safely discarded. This applies to all other resources that don't need to persist between frames.

But if different data needs to be used for each frame, or if generated data is used in the next frame, then You usually need another copy of a given resource. Updating data requires synchronization - to avoid waiting in such situations You need to have a copy a resource. So in case of uniform buffers, You update data in a given buffer and use it in a given frame. You cannot modify its contents until the frame is finished - so to prepare another frame of animation while the previous one is still being processed on a GPU, You need to use another copy.

Similarly if the generated data is required for the next frame (for example framebuffer used for screen space reflections). Reusing the same resource would cause its contents to be overwritten. That's why You need another copy.

You can find more information here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/api-without-secrets-the-practical-approach-to-vulkan-part-1

Comment: Even if my depth buffer is temporary having a single instance means 2 frames cannot use it at the same time. Is this guaranteed anywhere?

Comment: @RhuMage I suspect the tutorials just sync it wrong on the GPU. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: If You submit commands to the same queue, then they are processed sequentially. So first frame will use a given depth buffer, and after that the second frame. And despite the fact that some parts of a graphics pipeline can be processed in parallel, I doubt this is a problem here. And even so, render pass dependencies should do the trick.

Comment: @Ekzuzy Only `TOP` stage is processed sequentially (Submission order guarantee). In the linked tutorial only single dependecy exists (on `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT`), but depth `loadOp` happens in `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT`. There's no appropriate Semaphore either. Makes me think the tutorial is missynchronized (unless it relies on something obscure in the spec; which it should explain then).

Comment: @krOoze Maybe indeed the tutorial is not synchronized properly. I don't remember it too well. But I write generally. And I know that only the start of each command buffer is guaranteed to be processed in order. But I doubt that the same stage in two different frames will overlap. And even so I'm pretty sure dependencies should help in such cases (and maybe this is the missing part of the mentioned tutorial).

Comment: @Ekzuzy Thanks anyway, I am just being strict about the spec here. I belive it works mostly because `vkPresent` on many platforms (mesa, and prolly GDI) likely introduces implicit fence inside. I think I will ask at the `vkcube` repo, as this seems to be wherefrom all the tutorials copied this approach. Yeah, generally speaking, you can use one buffer IF you synchronize it properly... and unlike the uniforms, it should only need GPU-side synchronization.

Comment: @krOoze Yeah, I agree.